# Performance between Classic ASP Server and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

**Issue:**

Trying to get the same (or better) performance with a separate SQL Server 2017 and IIS 7.5 server than with having both on the same machine.

Trying to move toward scalability for future growth.

Using WebSurge on the same box that's running both IIS and SQL Server 2017 Developer with 32gb of ram on 6 cores and 12 logical processors, there are no major performance issues with the machine. We can run the code below on WebSurge at a rate of 4000 requests per second with great speed.

The Problem:

Once we run the same code on a separate IIS box and a separate SQL Server on the same gigabit connection on the local LAN, we can only get about 350 requests per second on the IIS running on its own box. Note: SQL Server is using <1% CPU on the box it is running on with these 350 requests, so it is not an issue with the query or SQL Server performance, as the same code runs over 4000 with IIS on the same machine.

The LAN cables are plugged into the same switch and PING is <1ms at all times from IIS to SQL Server.

What are we doing wrong where the completed requests slow down so drastically, but when run again on the same IIS/SQL Server box... it is over 4000 per second.

We are planning on a creating a large service soon were web traffic will well exceed 4000 requests per second so we will need additional servers, load balancers etc. We are currently trying to see why we can only handle 350 requests per second from an IIS box, not on the same machine as the server.

I'll also point out that the CPU is running nowhere above 50% in either scenario.

SQL Server only consumes approx 10% when running this code.

```
<%
rangedb="Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _ 
        "Data Source=10.10.1.220,1433;" & _ 
        "Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;" & _ 
        "Network=DBMSSOCN;" & _ 
        "User Id=xxxxxx;" & _ 
        "Password=xxxxxx" 

set cnn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

cnn.open rangedb

sqltext = "SELECT page_content,template_id FROM master_templates_data where  (template_id='165' or template_id='166' or template_id='167' or template_id='168' or template_id='169' or template_id='170' or template_id='171' or template_id='172' or template_id='173' or template_id='182' or template_id='183' or template_id='184' or template_id='185' or template_id='186' or template_id='187' or template_id='188' or template_id='189')"

rst.CursorLocation=2
rst.CursorType=0
rst.LockType=1
rst.Open sqltext,cnn

dataArray = rst.GetRows()

rst.close

cnn.close
%>
```

We have looked all over the Internet and cannot find a reason for this.

Any help would be appreciated!

(Yes, we know classic ASP is not the way to go for a project like this but we would like to solve this issue for our current situations)

If there is a better alternative such as MySQL and PHP/Linux we would be open to how the performance would be better.

This is our first time posting here so please be kind :)

Comment: This is a great question with lots of detail, I'm just not sure is relevant for [so].

Comment: Sorry if I have posted this in the wrong place. Is there a better venue to put this post instead? Again sorry, we don't normally post as we can normally find all answers on site like this but we are stuck on reasoning behind this one.

Comment: To be completely honest I'm not sure, but it is mainly about the difference in performance between two server setups and has nothing to do with the code. I would be inclined to suggest asking on [sf] but you might need to rephrase it a little, removing unnessasry reference to the Classic ASP code.

Comment: You'll likely find the issue is the speed of the harddisks versus the speed of the network between the Web and SQL Servers. If the disks read/write is greater than a Gibps it will always out perform the two server setup.

Comment: 350/sec seems much slower than it should be. I would look for something in the network stack on the SQL box like hips/antivirus. You might try a dummy query like `SELECT 1` for a baseline test.

Comment: A Gigabit network will give you [approx. 125 MBps](https://www.tomshardware.co.uk/gigabit-ethernet-bandwidth,review-31611-3.html), what are the disk read/write speeds, is it raided? It's possible [Windows 10 is doing some throttling](https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/2806-slow-network-throughput-windows-10-a.html) of it's own.

Comment: I can simply open the database connection and close it and get several thousand rps with not actually passing any command after its opened.

Comment: With a "select 1" as the statement, we jump from 350 to 900 rps

Its not the code, more than likely. Its something to do with the TCP between the 2 servers. Works with over 14,000 rps on the IIS/SQL machine together by just opening and closing the connection, and with SELECT 1 it is the same at about 14,000 rps with IIS and SQL on same machine.

Drive is Solid State where the test database resides.

Comment: I went ahead and posted in Server Fault as suggested. Appreciate the feedback.